# Change Subtotal on Cart and Checkout - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to **change the total** in the **cart** and **checkout**, *multiplying it by 10*. (because it currently shows me the 10% deposit price - Woocommerce Deposite plugin -, but I would like to display the total price without deposit).

So I thought about multiplying that by 10.

I would also like to **eliminate the row as in the image**, because it is useless to me.
[image]

The start string was called 'Subtotal' and I changed it to 'TOTAL'. I found this piece of code that references it.

```
<tr class="cart-subtotal">
            <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            <td data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Subtotal', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php wc_cart_totals_subtotal_html(); ?></td>
        </tr>
```

Can I add some code in functions.php to make these changes? Thanks a lot!

This change must also be activated in the checkout:
[image]

Comment: So you need to set up a child theme, and then override the related template via your child theme… see [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/). Then you will be able to make the necessary changes. The related template file is [`cart/cart-totals.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-totals.php). So in your child theme you will create a folder named "woocommerce" with a subfolder named "cart"...

Comment: Inside that folder you will add a copy from WooCommerce plugin > templates > cart > cart-totals.php. Now you can edit this file (in your child theme), that will self override the woocommerce one. When woocommerce or your theme will be updated, you will not loose your customizations. for checkout the file is `checkout/review-order.php`(do nearly the same thing, adding a subfolder "checkout" in the child theme "woocommerce" folder…).

Comment: Hello @LoicTheAztec thanks for you answer. Yep, I performed these steps, but in the code I copied I can't figure out what changes I need to make. I tried to multiply the strings by 10, but at the frontend level it sometimes remains unchanged and other times the site fails